# Minesweeper Clearing Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, minesweeper

I'm attempting to recreate Minesweeper in flash for a project and I've gotten as far as placing mines and numbers. I can't seem to figure out the recursive algorithm for the expansion of clicking on a tile and clearing its neighbors. There are two arrays, _map holds the background + mines & numbers, _clickable map holds the tiles that sit on top of the background. So basically, what I'm asking for is help with recursion. If this isn't clear enough, I'll update the question with necessary information.

```
private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    trace("on Click");

    var symbol = e.currentTarget;
    var tempTileMask:TileMask = symbol;
    var tempTile:Tile = _map[tempTileMask.yCoord][tempTileMask.xCoord]

    if (tempTile.hasMine)
    {
        for (var i:int = _gridSize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            for (var j:int = _gridSize - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                var temp:TileMask = _clickableMap[i][j];
                removeChild(temp);
            }

        //explosion();

        //gameOver();
    }

    if (tempTile.hasNumber)
    {
        removeChild(tempTileMask);
        tempTile.cleared = true;
    }

    else
    {
        clearTiles(tempTile.xCoord, tempTile.yCoord);
    }
}
```

This is the function I modified to clear mines

```
function clearTiles( x:int, y:int )
{
    // Get an object that contains the tile information for the location
    // we are checking
    if(_map[y][x] != null) 
    {
        var tempTile:Tile = _map[y][x];
        var tempTileMask:TileMask = _clickableMap[y][x];

        // Check if the location we are checking is out of the bounds of the
        // playable area

        trace(tempTile);
        if ( tempTile.outOfBounds(x, y) )
        {
            return;
        }

        // If the tile has already been revealed then there is nothing to do

        trace("before clearing");
        if ( tempTile.cleared )
        {
            trace("clearing tile");
            return;
        }

        // If the tile hasn't been revealed and it's an empty square we
        // reveal the location then call this function again for each
        // surrounding block

        trace("before check for surrounding tiles");
        if ( tempTile.hasNumber != true && tempTile.hasMine != true )
        {
            trace("check for surrounding tiles");

            // Remove the mask hiding the tiles property
            removeChild( tempTileMask );
            // Set the tile as cleared
            tempTile.cleared = true;

            if(_map[tempTile.yCoord][tempTile.xCoord - 1] != null)
            {
                var tile1:Tile =_map[tempTile.yCoord][tempTile.xCoord - 1]

                if(!tile1.cleared)
                    clearTiles( tempTile.xCoord - 1 , tempTile.yCoord ); //Check tile to the left
            }

            if(_map[tempTile.yCoord][tempTile.xCoord + 1] != null)
            {
                var tile2:Tile =_map[tempTile.yCoord][tempTile.xCoord + 1]

                if(!tile2.cleared)
                    clearTiles( tempTile.xCoord + 1 , tempTile.yCoord ); //Check tile to the left
            }

            if(_map[tempTile.yCoord - 1][tempTile.xCoord] != null)
            {
                var tile3:Tile =_map[tempTile.yCoord - 1][tempTile.xCoord]

                if(!tile3.cleared)
                    clearTiles( tempTile.xCoord, tempTile.yCoord - 1 ); //Check tile to the left
            }

            if(_map[tempTile.yCoord + 1][tempTile.xCoord] != null)
            {
                var tile4:Tile =_map[tempTile.yCoord + 1][tempTile.xCoord]

                if(!tile4.cleared)
                    clearTiles( tempTile.xCoord, tempTile.yCoord + 1 ); //Check tile to the left
            }

            if(_map[tempTile.yCoord - 1][tempTile.xCoord - 1] != null)
            {
                var tile5:Tile =_map[tempTile.yCoord - 1][tempTile.xCoord - 1]

                if(!tile5.cleared)
                    clearTiles( tempTile.xCoord - 1, tempTile.yCoord - 1 ); //Check tile to the left
            }

            if(_map[tempTile.yCoord + 1][tempTile.xCoord + 1] != null)
            {
                var tile6:Tile =_map[tempTile.yCoord + 1][tempTile.xCoord + 1]

                if(!tile6.cleared)
                    clearTiles( tempTile.xCoord + 1, tempTile.yCoord + 1 ); //Check tile to the left
            } 

            if(_map[tempTile.yCoord - 1][tempTile.xCoord + 1] != null)
            {
                var tile7:Tile =_map[tempTile.yCoord - 1][tempTile.xCoord + 1]

                if(!tile7.cleared)
                    clearTiles( tempTile.xCoord + 1, tempTile.yCoord - 1 ); //Check tile to the left
            }


            if(_map[tempTile.yCoord + 1][tempTile.xCoord - 1] != null)
            {
                var tile8:Tile =_map[tempTile.yCoord + 1][tempTile.xCoord - 1]

                if(!tile8.cleared)
                    clearTiles( tempTile.xCoord - 1, tempTile.yCoord + 1 ); //Check tile to the left
            }
        }
    }
    else
        return;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please forgive if I screw up actionscript syntax.  I just love recursive functions so I had to answer this.  I'll just paste the code with the most accurate comments I can muster.  If you have questions please ask.  I'm sure you can convert anything you need to the appropriate function calls, property references etc.

```
// Function to check if a tile is an empty space and then call
// itself for the surrounding tiles

function clearTiles( x:int, y:int ):void
{
    // Check if the location we are checking is out of the bounds of the
    // playable area
    if ( outOfBounds( x, y ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    // Get an object that contains the tile information for the location
    // we are checking
    var tempTile:Tile = _map[x][y];


    // If the tile has already been revealed then there is nothing to do
    if ( tempTile.cleared )
    {
        return;
    }

    // If the tile is a number then reveal it and return without checking
    // surrounding tiles
    var tempTileMask:DisplayObject = getTileMask(x,y);
    // since we're no longer in the click handler context, we need
    // to initialize the variable with something [TODO]
    if ( tempTile.hasNumber )
    {
        removeChild( tempTileMask );
        tempTile.cleared = true;
        return;
    }


    // If the tile hasn't been revealed and it's an empty square we
    // reveal the location then call this function again for each
    // surrounding block

    if ( tempTile.isEmpty )
    {
        // Remove the mask hiding the tiles property
        removeChild( tempTileMask );
        // Set the tile as cleared
        tempTile.cleared = true;

        clearTiles( tempTile.x - 1 , tempTile.y ); //Check tile to the left
        clearTiles( tempTile.x + 1 , tempTile.y ); //Check tile to the right
        clearTiles( tempTile.x , tempTile.y - 1 ); //Check tile above
        clearTiles( tempTile.x , tempTile.y + 1 ); //Check tile below
    }

}
```

You'll have to create an outOfBounds() function to just check if the X and Y being checked are larger than the current game board.  It looks like you reference _gridSize as a static number, so I assume all of your game boards are squares (ex: 4x4, 9x9, 120x120).  In which case you can use something like this:

```
function outOfBounds( int x, int y )
{
    if ( x < 0 )
    {
        return true;
    }

    if ( y < 0 )
    {
        return true;
    }

    if ( x > _gridSize - 1 )
    {
        return true;
    }

    if ( y > _gridSize -1 )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by tempTile.outOfBounds()? Is that a function that I need to write, or is it something part of flash that, I don't know, checks the bounds of an array?

Comment: I just added an edit to help clarify.  I have a LOT of experience with crashes because I reference array elements that are out of the array's bounds.  So one of the first things I do now when handling arrays is to make sure I don't reference something that's not there.  The code I gave you definitely can't just be copy pasted, but hopefully you see how I structured the recursive function and you can pass any arguments you find suitable.

Comment: I'm having an issue with your code, where it will clear some of the tiles that are neighbors and have neither mines nor numbers, but not all that are adjacent

Comment: Could you edit your original post so I can see how you've implemented it?  The idea is that it checks a tile and if it's empty it will reveal it, then call the same function for each tile immediately surrounding it (north,south,east,west).

Comment: @user3523222 OH!!! I haven't played minesweeper in so long I forgot how the game worked.  I think you're asking why the numbers that are next to empty spots aren't also being revealed.  I forgot that is how the game is played.  I made a small change to my solution for clear tiles.  Basically during the clear tiles function I check if it's a numbered tile and if it is I reveal it and return.  Oversight on my part because I haven't played the game in so long.

Comment: @user3523222 Reading your edit I can't seem to find where it's failing, unless you're talking about number tiles not being revealed.  Honestly I think if you include my `if ( tempTile.hasNumber )` section that I edited in then it should work fine.  If not then feel free to follow up here.

Comment: I keep getting this error in flash, but everything seems to clear just fine TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at GameLoop/clearTiles()
 at GameLoop/clearTiles()
 at GameLoop/onClick()

Comment: @user3523222 If everything is clearing fine, that's great.  As for TypeErrors, I can't help you.  I actually have never used AS3 before and I'm not familiar with it's syntax or it's Type casting.  In my offered solution I just tried to mimic the syntax you provided.  If you can't diagnose the problem try reposting as an action-script3 problem and see if one of the AS3 experts can look at it.  I'm sure someone would be able to easily say something like, "Oh, on line 52 you didn't cast a variable" or something.  Good luck with your project! :D

Comment: @StackofPancakes Here, fixed the syntax for you. Note, your function does not have a `tileMask` reference ready, so I've added a line OP needs to implement to get mask sprite for adjacent tiles in case of zero on the current tile.

Comment: @user3523222 The function lacked the `tileMask` reference that originally has been assigned in the event listener. Now you have to use a function to get a specific tile mask, I've named it `getTileMask`, the interface expected is `function getTileMask(x:int,y:int):DisplayObject`.